# OperationalError: near "?": syntax error

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

```sql
create table Comment(
    cid integer primary key autoincrement,
    content string not null
);
```

```
db.execute('insert into Comment values ?', (request.form['content']))
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this

```
VALUES = ?
```